# How to bake floating geometry to normal map?

Tags: texture-baking

For the past days I've been trying to find a way to bake floating geometry onto any mesh that's not a simple plane. Now the problem isn't as much getting the geometry to bake properly on the face that I intend to, but the fact that it creates a problem on the faces on the opposite side of the mesh.

[image: This is a simple example to showcase my problem]

[image: This is the result I get]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: could you please share this file?

Comment: @moonboots Well I didn't save that specific one since I just created it for the purpose of illustrating my problem, but I recreated it here: https://www.mediafire.com/file/shgvwsz2bsb1x6n/floater.rar/file

Comment: sorry I can't unrar your file, could you please try another format?

Comment: Yup, maybe ZIP works: https://www.mediafire.com/file/sf6ci50ls25b3vx/floater.zip/file

Comment: Why don't you just bake it to a plane of the same size of one of the cube's faces, and then apply the normal map to the cube in the cubes material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what’s happening. Let say you have object A (the highpoly object you need to bake) and object B (the lowpoly, the object on which you want to use the bake)

- The bake is a kind of scan that begins from the faces and goes in the opposite direction of their normals, it goes as long as necessary, until it hits the surface of the object that needs to be baked. That’s the basis of baking (as I understand it). So here is what happens for the top face: With a *Ray Distance* of 0 the scan begins from the top face, it goes downwards and hit nothing, so no baking.

[image]

- If some faces of object A go a bit beyond the surface of object B, you need to make the scan begin a bit before with the help of the *Ray Distance* value. It’s the case here, object A is out of object B, so you need to have a *Ray Distance* value higher than 0, in your file your value was a bit low, so it didn’t scan the whole object A, you need to increase the value a bit, 0.2 seems good.

[image]

- The bottom face of your object B scanned in the opposite direction of its normal as it is supposed to do, so it scanned upwards until it hit object A. But in this direction it hits faces that are flipped, so the scan gave incorrect colors.

[image]

- I suppose you didn't expect the bottom face to have any baking. In that case the simplest solutions are either to paint your normal map with purple, or to close the bottom of your object A with a face so that the object won't be scanned by the object B bottom face (only slopes can be scanned, not surfaces that are parallel or perpendicular to the scan direction).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wait, now that's something I wasn't aware of, is Blender scanning in the direction opposite of the normal? Thanks!

Comment: Yes it took me time to understand, I haven't found a good explanation anywhere. By the way I've edited to add a simple solution in your case, just close the bottom face of your shape.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot with understanding and fixing the problem. In case anyone will look for a solution for this in the future I'll leave here a couple of other solutions.
1. [Duplicating the faces affected by the baking](https://i.gyazo.com/c72f7a38bb9589ad79b6a0d6cc3257a4.png)
2. [Duplicating the entire object and baking it onto itself alongside the floating geometry](https://i.gyazo.com/0516b697b10006dd3bf50c819d451a94.png)
3. [Adding a solifiy modifier to the floating geometry and making the bottom planar/flat](https://i.gyazo.com/6533aa63b735698c58730c677bacda2a.png)